# How can I avoid using the NOT IN and the SUBSELECT in the following query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I avoid using the NOT IN subselect in this query **and also avoid the subselect** ?

```
select idTipoDocumento,idDocumentoTarea
from ArchivosTarea as a 
inner join Tarea as b on a.idEstadoTarea=b.idTarea
where b.idTarea = 160 
and idDocumentoTarea not in (select idDocumentoTarea

from ArchivosTarea as a 
inner join tiposArchivos as b on a.idTipoDocumento = b.idTipoArchivo 
inner join documentoSolicitud as c on b.idTipoArchivo = c.Id_tipo_archivo
inner join tarea as d on a.idEstadoTarea=d.idTarea
where d.idTarea = 160)
```

I know that probably a LEFT JOIN or something like that should do the trick but I have tried that and it does not provide me the same results as this query.

The actual idea is to avoid the SUBSELECT (of the WHERE) and also avoid the NOT IN.

Comment: MICROSOFT SQL SERVER

Comment: Just from curiousity: NOT EXISTS is not an option?

Comment: I also dont want to use the SUBSELECT actually (there is a policy in my work of avoiding SUBSELECTS as much as possible)

Comment: I suppose you mean a sub query in your where clause is frowned upon. A subquery in general is pretty rational, i.e --> SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM)AS Subquery, in fact you would not be able to perform a large chunk of sql logic without using subqueries.

Comment: @lrb I know it is rational, but I want to know if there is a way to avoid its use and learn in the process ;-)

Comment: I think I am agreeing with you. I only use subqueries in a where clause as last resort when it can't be avoided in a rational way. However, I use queries of queries almost everyday.

Comment: Using `NOT EXISTS(...)` is the preferred way. Let those that make the policy explain why they don't like subqueries in the WHERE clause. It doesn't make much sense, sometimes there's no other way or no better way.

Answer (score 1):

Using left join:

```
Select A.idTipoDocumento,A.idDocumentoTarea from
(select idTipoDocumento,idDocumentoTarea
from ArchivosTarea as a 
inner join Tarea as b on a.idEstadoTarea=b.idTarea
where b.idTarea = 160)A
left outer join
(select idDocumentoTarea from ArchivosTarea as a 
inner join tiposArchivos as b on a.idTipoDocumento = b.idTipoArchivo 
inner join documentoSolicitud as c on b.idTipoArchivo = c.Id_tipo_archivo
inner join tarea as d on a.idEstadoTarea=d.idTarea
where d.idTarea = 160)B
on A.idDocumentoTarea=B.idDocumentoTarea
where B.idDocumentoTarea is null
```

Comment: I have updated my question since I also dont want to use the SUBSELECT since is "forbidden" in my current work

Comment: What do you mean by forbidden? Actually this query uses derived tables and not subqueries: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/derived-table-vs-subquery/

Comment: so that "select a....from (select..." is not a subquery ? ...and by fordbiden i mean is considered a bad practice in my current work

Comment: It is not a bad practice, and it can be a good practice in a lot of cases.

Comment: I still need to know if this can be done without any subselect of any kind (I wish i could change the rules at my work ;-)

Comment: Without knowing your tables structure, what every field means and what do you want to do exactly, this is not doable. Plus, you need to know that you are not able to do a lot of things in SQL without using Subqueries or derived tables.

Comment: since all the fields and relations are mention in the provided question there is no need to know any other fields since they don't participate in the relation between the data

Answer (score 0):

It happens that SQL Server has antijoin aka semiminus aka EXCEPTION JOIN. It return rows in the left argument that don't match when joined by the right.

```
select idTipoDocumento,idDocumentoTarea
from ArchivosTarea as a 
inner join Tarea as b on a.idEstadoTarea=b.idTarea
and b.idTarea = 160 
exception join (
    select idDocumentoTarea
    from ArchivosTarea as a 
    inner join tiposArchivos as b on a.idTipoDocumento = b.idTipoArchivo 
    inner join documentoSolicitud as c on b.idTipoArchivo = c.Id_tipo_archivo
    inner join tarea as d on a.idEstadoTarea=d.idTarea
    where d.idTarea = 160)
```

You *can* do this with LEFT JOIN. Also using NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I have updated my question since I also dont want to use the SUBSELECT since is "forbidden" in my current work